# Getting and setting values from Redux Store with Redux Saga

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, saga

I am trying to return a token without an API but it keeps returning undefined. The purpose at the moment is just to optionally show two elements dependent on whether or not there is a token in the props, preparing it for later when I actually implement the API.

I have tried different saga effects and amended my code more times than I can count. There does not seem to be a lot of information regarding setting initial state so I was wondering if that may be the issue and I am trying to select state that does not exist? Though I believe this should be handled by the reducer?

My code is as follows:

redux/store.js:

```js
import { connectRouter, routerMiddleware } from 'connected-react-router';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';

import reducers from './reducers';
import rootSaga from './sagas';

const history = createBrowserHistory();
const routeMiddleware = routerMiddleware(history);
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

const middlewares = [thunk, sagaMiddleware, routeMiddleware];

const composeEnhancers =
    typeof window === 'object' && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__
        ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__({
            // Specify extension’s options like name, actionsBlacklist, actionsCreators, serialize...
        })
        : compose;

const store = createStore(
    combineReducers({
        ...reducers,
        router: connectRouter(history),
    }),
    composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middlewares))
);

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

export { store, history };
```

redux/reducers.js:

```js
import Auth from './auth/reducer';

export default {
    Auth
};
```

redux/saga.js:

```js
import { all } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import authSaga from './auth/saga';

export default function* rootSaga(getState) {
    yield all([
        authSaga()
    ]);
};
```

redux/auth/actions.js:

```js
export const checkAuthAction = (value) => ({
    type: 'CHECK_AUTH',
    value
});
```

redux/auth/reducer.js:

```js
import { checkAuthAction } from "./actions";

const initialState = {
    token: true
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {

        case 'CHECK_AUTH':
            return {
                ...state,
                token: action.token
            };

        default:
            return state;

    };
};

export default reducer;
```

redux/auth/saga.js

```js
import { select, take } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { checkAuthAction } from './actions';

// Selectors
const getToken = (state) => state.token;

function* authSaga() {
    const token = yield select(getToken);
    console.log(token);
};

export default authSaga;
```

Edit: forgot to include the component itself.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class Nav extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <nav className="nav">
                {this.props.token ? (
                    <Col type="flex" align="center" className="nav__list__item" md={6}>
                        <Link to="/logout"><IntlMessages id="nav.logout.link" /></Link>
                    </Col>
                ) : (
                    <Col type="flex" align="center" className="nav__list__item" md={6}>
                        <Link to="/login"><IntlMessages id="nav.login.link" /></Link>
                    </Col>
                )}
            </nav>
        );
    };
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
   token: state.token
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    CHECK_AUTH: 'CHECK_AUTH'
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Nav);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the token in the component you should change the `mapStateToProps` function:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
   token: state.Auth.token
});
```

In order to get it in the saga you should change the `getToken` selector

```
const getToken = (state) => state.Auth.token;
```